# django-cms 3.0 page blank and plugin can't select

Tags: django-cms

i try to install django-cms 3.0 beta 2 on python 3.3

according document tutorial. i set up all part,except one "add to a page", i can't find the sub menus(The admin interfaces shows you theses placeholders as sub menus).

that make me can't select plugin to use display content, my home page still blank.

anyone can help?

Comment: Don't understand. You mean that you are trying to add plugins from the admin page ?

Comment: that's right. sorry about i can't describe my question clearly.

Answer (score 1):

So starting with django-cms 3.0, the backend plugin editing was completely moved to the frontend. This means that you can only edit page information through the admin, but will have to use the cms frontend to modify plugins. This was a way to remove the limitations set by the admin and allow you to modify content more freely. Give it a shot :)